# Syntax error with FOR nested inside IF in bash.

Tags: bash

Im trying to make this pipeline more flexible. So say I want to be able to easily switch the number of times a for loop is run, based on whether or not I want to analyse all my data.

```
#!/bin/bash
#AllCohorts='Yes'
AllCohorts='NotAll'
groups=$(wc -l Groups | awk '{print $1}' ) 

if [[ $AllCohorts == *Yes* ]]
then
    for pheno in `seq 1 $groups`; 
    do
    out=$(sed -n "$pheno"'p' Groups) 
    whichPheno=$pheno
elif [[ $AllCohorts == *Not* ]]
then
    nbGroups=$(wc -l TestingGroups | awk '{print$1}')
    for pheno in `seq 1 $nbGroups`; 
    do
    out=$(sed -n "$pheno"'p' Groups) 
    hit=$(grep -n $out TestingGroups) 
    whichPheno=${hit%:*} 
fi
```

This gives an error:

```
$ sh run_gene_tests.sh
run_gene_tests.sh: line 29: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
run_gene_tests.sh: line 29: `elif [[ $AllCohorts == *Not* ]]'
```

What Im wondering is, does the code you have in between the if and elif/fi have to be self contained? or can you do what im trying here and just have the for loop starting in one of two ways based on AllCohorts

Comment: You are missing the `done` from your `for` loop.

Comment: You're missing a `done`

Comment: By the way, if you just want the number of lines in a file you can do `wc -l < filename`. This passes the contents of the file on standard input so you don't need to then use another tool to remove the filename from the output.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `done` at the end of the `for` loops

```
if [[ $AllCohorts == *Yes* ]]
then
    for pheno in `seq 1 $groups`; 
    do
        out=$(sed -n "$pheno"'p' Groups) 
        whichPheno=$pheno
    done
elif [[ $AllCohorts == *Not* ]]
then
    nbGroups=$(wc -l TestingGroups | awk '{print$1}')
    for pheno in `seq 1 $nbGroups`; 
    do
        out=$(sed -n "$pheno"'p' Groups) 
        hit=$(grep -n $out TestingGroups) 
        whichPheno=${hit%:*} 
    done
fi
```

Comment: Am I? Theres a lot more code after this bit to run, that Ive left outside of this IF block because its the same for both conditions. I have the done after this. The two "For"s here share a done

Comment: You can't share a `done` between two `for`s. They have to be nested properly.

Comment: But only one of the fors gets used because of the if. I still cant do it?

Comment: No, you can't. The body of an `if` or `elif` must be self-contained. Look at the syntax in the bash manual.

Comment: @pepsimax The thing to realize is that `done` is not a separate command that jumps back to the previous loop. `for ..; do ..; done` is a single compound command, and has to be specified completely. That's why you can't share a `done` like you would share a `rm` for cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Some enhancements using less external tools:

```
readarray grouptab < Groups || exit 1

if [[ "$AllCohorts" == *Yes* ]]; then
    for ((pheno=1;pheno <= groups; pheno++)); do     # use for loop
        out=${grouptab[pheno+1]}                     # avoid sed
        whichPheno=$pheno
    done
elif [[ "$AllCohorts" == *Not* ]]; then
    nbGroups=$(wc -l < TestingGroups)                # avoid awk using <
    for ((pheno=1;pheno <= nbGroups; pheno++)); do   # use for loop
        out=${grouptab[pheno+1]}                     # avoid sed
        hit=$(grep -n "$out" TestingGroups) 
        whichPheno=${hit%:*} 
    done
fi
```